# How does this high impedance circuit stage work

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors

The current i1 flows through Q3 and current i2 flows through Q4. It looks like D5 is trying to mirror the current flowing through it via Q6. D6 is trying to mirror the current flowing through it in Q5. It also looks lie Q3,Q4 are biased using D7,D8. But if Q3,Q4 are biased using D7,D8 but should also allow a current of i1,i2 to flow through it . How does this work?(i1,i2 doesnt seem to be small signal current)

What happens if I remove Q3,Q4 and D7,D8?

[image]

Comment: if you remove Q3,Q4 and D7,D8,  then you have no signal connection between the input and the output

Comment: I suspect that you're asking what happens if you remove those and connect the collectors of Q1 and Q2 to the collectors of Q6 and D5, respectively.  Probably (I'm not an IC designer) you won't be presenting as high-impedance an output at Vc, and your gain will go down.  I suspect that reason for Q5 and D6 is to increase the output impedance of the current mirror, just as Q3 and Q4 would increase the output impedance of the input stage.  The end result would be a Really Freaking High impedance at the point \$V_C\$, for (presumably) more gain at lower current, and a smaller \$C_C\$ to boot.

Comment: \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ aren't small signal currents: \$I=I_1+I_2\$. You've got a Wilson mirror (\$Q_5\$, \$Q_6\$, \$D_5\$, and \$D_6\$), a long-tailed pair (\$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$), a fixed voltage reference held against \$V_\text{CC}\$ (\$D_7\$, \$D_7\$, and its current sink), a pair of emitter followers tied to that voltage reference designed to mitigate the Early Effect in \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ and divert the differential currents to the Wilson mirror, and the shared collectors of \$Q_4\$ and \$Q_6\$, that can swing over quite a range, presenting \$V_C\$ to the simple output stage (with added NFB.)

Comment: @jonk that makes a lt of sense. Could you explain how the fixed voltage applied would help reduce early effect?

Comment: @ton I probably should write an answer, then, if you can't "see it." What's happening is that the collectors of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are held at the same fixed voltage relative to the (+) rail by the emitters of \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$. Since the \$V_\text{CE}\$ of both \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ is therefore fixed (almost, as there will be slight variations depending on the small input signals), the Early Effect doesn't vary (it exists, of course, but is held constant which is a good thing.) Do you need a broader answer?

Comment: @ton If I had to guess (and I do), I suspect that the current sources for \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are developed by reflecting their current sink upwards to a simple current mirror pair. They'd need to keep it to just simple BJTs on the topside because of the low overhead required given \$D_7\$ + \$D_8\$, followed by the \$V_\text{BE}\$ for \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$ -- which don't leave much room at all. (Another reason the Early Effect needed to be nipped in the bud, so to speak.)

Answer (score 0):

The top of D5 would clamp the Q2collector to 2 volts above -rail.

And Q6 would similarly pull down on collector of Q1, tho not with diode clamps.